# What will be format of first define() and require() function in requirejs project

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Question#1: After requirejs configuration, what will be the format of first require() call to load my main.js

### App.js

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'lib',
    paths: {
        app: '../app'
    }
});
require(['app/main'], function(m){
    console.log('loading m...');
});
```

Question#2: And what will be format of first define() function in main.js file.

### Main.js

```
define(function () {
    var messages = require('./messages');
    var print = require('print');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only issue I see in the code you show is that your `main.js` should have its `define` call like this:

```
define(function (require) {
  var messages = require('./messages');
  var print = require('print');
});
```

If you pass a function as the first parameter to `define`, RequireJS will call it with the special modules `require`, `exports` and `module` but at a minimum you must declare the first parameter so that the calls you made inside your factory function are to the *local* `require` (passed to the function) rather than the *global* `require`. There are a number of issues if you call the global `require`. One of them is that relative module references like `./messages` won't be resolved correctly.

The `require` call you have in your `app.js` looks fine.